# Remove wp-login link from auto generated wordpress's email

Tags: user-registration

Am trying to edit the text inside the auto generated email wordpress send to the users when they are trying to register. The specific email has a link to wp-login which i don't want.
Is there any plugin or code to modify?
Any help is appreciate

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code does not work, so i decided after some failed codes i found to use my mind and add 301 redirection

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to the email sent after new subscriber registered to the site?

If so, it is a pluggable function, which means you can over ride it as you need.

Put this code in your theme functions.php.

```
if( ! function_exists('wp_new_user_notification') ) {
    function wp_new_user_notification($user_id, $plaintext_pass) {
        $user = new WP_User($user_id);
        $user_login = stripslashes($user->user_login);
        $greetings = $user_login;
        if ($user->display_name != '') {
            $greetings = $user->display_name; 
        }
        $user_email = stripslashes($user->user_email);
        $email_subject = sprintf(__('Welcome to %1$s %2$s!', 'cell-email'), get_bloginfo('name'), $greetings);

        $message = 'Your welcome message here';

        wp_mail($user_email, $email_subject, $message);

    }
}
```